# Override helper list footer in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, helper, prestashop-1.6

I would like to change admin products actions bulks, so i'm creating a module to do the trick,
In my module, i have not any controller, i'm overriding the adminProductsController, and i would like to override ADMIN/themes/default/template/helpers/list/footer_list.tpl, i tried to place it under /override/controllers/admin/templates/helpers/list, but i'm getting the default template.

In Helper.php

```
public function createTemplate($tpl_name)
{
    var_dump($this->override_folder);
    var_dump($this->module);

    exit;

    if ($this->override_folder)
    {
        if ($this->context->controller instanceof ModuleAdminController)
            $override_tpl_path = $this->context->controller->getTemplatePath().$this->override_folder.$this->base_folder.$tpl_name;
        elseif ($this->module)
            $override_tpl_path = _PS_MODULE_DIR_.$this->module->name.'/views/templates/admin/_configure/'.$this->override_folder.$this->base_folder.$tpl_name;
        else
        {
            if (file_exists($this->context->smarty->getTemplateDir(1).$this->override_folder.$this->base_folder.$tpl_name))
                $override_tpl_path = $this->context->smarty->getTemplateDir(1).$this->override_folder.$this->base_folder.$tpl_name;
            elseif (file_exists($this->context->smarty->getTemplateDir(0).'controllers'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$this->override_folder.$this->base_folder.$tpl_name))
                $override_tpl_path =   $this->context->smarty->getTemplateDir(0).'controllers'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$this->override_folder.$this->base_folder.$tpl_name;

        }
    }
    elseif ($this->module)
        $override_tpl_path = _PS_MODULE_DIR_.$this->module->name.'/views/templates/admin/_configure/'.$this->base_folder.$tpl_name;
```

I'm getting NULL for $this->override_folder, i tried

```
$helper->override_folder = $this->tpl_folder;
```

In AdminController.php, renderList function.

Any one could help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the file in override/controllers/admin/templates/products/helpers/list